# Find $k$ so that $|a_n\;|≤Cn^{-k}$,$\,$ $|b_n\;|≤Cn^{-k}$ => $f∈C^1(T)$ ($a_n$,$b_n$ are the Fourier coefficients of f)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to find k that when $|a_n\;|≤Cn^{-k}$,$|b_n\;|≤Cn^{-k}$, ($|a_0\;|≤C$),  f satisfies $f∈C^1(T)$ which can proof Fourier series is converged. I feel k may be $1$ but I don't know how to proof it.

Comment: It is better to use $\implies$ (code : \implies) than $=>$. We also have  the symbol $\iff$ (code: \iff).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Apologies if this has already been said - MSE is telling me an answer already exists but I can't see it...)

No, $f=\sum_1^\infty\frac{\cos(nx)}n$ shows that $k=1$ does not even imply $f$ is continuous. (Because it's clear that $\sigma_n(f,0)\to\infty$.) Similarly, if $f=\sum\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}$ then $f$ is certainly continuous, but not continuously differentiable; thus $k=2$ is not enough.

Otoh if $k>2$ then $f\in C^1$, roughly  because $\sum |n|^{-k+1}<\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is in $L^{2}$ then $\sum a_k^2 + b_k^2 <\infty$
Since derivative of $f$ has Fourier coefficients $k*a_k$ if the derivative belongs to $L^2$ then $\sum (k*a_k)^2 + (k*b_k)^2 < \infty$ .
Now, using Cauchy-Schwartz one gets this estimate
$$\sum |a_k| + |b_k| = \sum k*|a_k|/k + k*|b_k|/k <= (\sum (k*a_k)^2 + (k*b_k)^2) * (\sum 1/k^2)$$
So, if $\sum (k*a_k)^2 + (k*b_k)^2 < \infty$ then $\sum |a_k| + |b_k| < \infty$ which implies that $f$ has absolutely convergent Fourier series and is continuous.
In short, if $|k*a_k| < 1/k^{1+s}$ and $|k*b_k| < 1/k^{1+s}$ where $s > 1/2$ then $f$ is in $C^{0}(T)$
Using this trick multi times, one gets - if $|k*a_k| < 1/k^{m+s}$ and  $|k*b_k| < 1/k^{m+s}$ then $f$ is in $C^{m-1}(T)$.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you changed the notation... (your $k$ is $n$ in the OP, while $k$ is the _exponent_ in the OP...)

Comment: You are right, it is unfortunate but I hope still readable.